# Bitwise operation dissection

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am in need of a hash value calculated on an IP address and a port number. I have found the following example, and through trail, I can see it returns a three-digit hash value which is fine by me.
However, I would like to know what happens in a little further detail, and I have a hard time figuring it out.

Here is the code snippet:

```
((addr.s_addr ^ (addr.s_addr>>8)^ntohs(port) & 255);
```

addr.s_addr is an unsigned long (32 bit).
Port is unsigned short (16 bit).

An IP address value of 192.168.50.70 and the port number 60049 returns the hash value 249 (when printed out with %d).

Could anyone help me understand what the operation actually does? :)

Thank you.

Kind regards
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no great mystery: It XORs (^) adds.s_addr with itself shifted 8 spaces to the right; then xors it with the port number, and finally ANDs the whole thing by 255 to limit it to 8 bytes in length.

Comment: ... which is actually quite bad: only the rightmost 16 bit of the ip-address participate in the hash (which is fine iff the addresses are restricted to 192.168.x.y) and only the eight rightmost bits of portnum participate in the hash value. But it **may** be good enough for the particular application.

Comment: Well, it's probably good enough for a 256-bucket hash map; although it's likely that the method could use some improvement.